# File Retention Script

Tags: batch-file

I have a directory that has a 10 sub-directories.  Each of these holds different .bak files.  I'm trying to create a script that will check to see if X number of files are there and if the number of files exceeds X, it deletes the oldest file.  In other words, I want 20 iterations of a .bak file.  When the 21st one shows up, I want the batch file to delete the oldest one.
Is this possible?
If so, can I create a single script that looks in all the sub-directories?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: the number of files should not be exceed in the subdirectory or it's for all the files?

Answer (score 2):

Two options included. The first one will leave `%maxFiles%` `bak` files under each of the folders. The second one (windows Vista or later OS is required as robocopy is used to obtain the sorted list of files) will leave `%maxFiles%` in total

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "rootFolder=%cd%"
    set "maxFiles=20"

    rem Option 1 - Keep %maxFiles% inside each of the subfolders
    for /d /r "%rootFolder%" %%z in (*) do for /f "skip=%maxFiles% delims=" %%a in (
        'dir /tc /o-d /a-d /b "%%~fz\*.bak" 2^>nul'
    ) do echo del "%%~fz\%%~nxa"

    echo ------------------------------

    rem Option 2 - Keep %maxFiles% in total under all the subfolders
    for /f "skip=%maxFiles% tokens=2,*" %%a in ('
        robocopy "%rootFolder%" "%rootFolder%" *.bak /l /nocopy /is /s /njh /njs /ndl /nc /ns /ts
        ^| findstr /v /r /e /i /c:"%rootFolder:\=\\%\\[^\\]*" 
        ^| sort /r
    ') do echo del "%%b"
```

`del` commands are only echoed to console. If the output is correct, remove the `echo` command to remove the files

Answer (score 0):

assumes that you want to check the number of files from the parent directory.Can be done also for each sub-directory.

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "max_number_files=20"
set "parrent_dir=c:\whatever_you_need"
set "extension=.bak"

pushd "%parrent_dir%"
set "count=0"

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /s /b /a:-d /o:-d /t:c *%extension%') do (
    set /a count=count+1
    if 1!count! GTR 1!max_number_files! (
        rem  --- remove the echo to activate deletion 
        echo del /q /f "%%~a"
    )
)
popd
endlocal
endlocal
```

Answer (score 0):

This will check each folder under `d:\base\folder` and if there are more than 20 `*.bak` files it will remove the oldest ones so only 20 *.bak file remain, in each folder.

Test it on some sample folders.

```
@echo off
for /d /r "d:\base\folder" %%a in (*) do (
   pushd "%%a"
      for /f "skip=20 delims=" %%b in ('dir /b /a-d /o:-d *.bak ') do del "%%b"
   popd
)
```